# How to get the line height of a span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

Is there a way to get the `line-height` of a `span` (or other inline element) in JavaScript/jQuery?

I need the **exact computed `line-height` in pixels**, not values of the sort `1.2em`, `normal` or heuristics like `fontSize * 1.5`.

What I need to do is stretch the background of a `span` to fill the whole height of the line. I figured that I could add paddings to stretch the span, but for this I need the exact `line-height`. If someone can offer another approach, this would also be helpful.

Comment: Your span need to have display:block, something like `span {line-height:12px; display:block;}`

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to do this is:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
var lineHeight = style.getPropertyValue('line-height');
```

This will get the calculate value of the line height without using jQuery and works on all browsers from IE9 onwards.

Comment: This will return `"normal"` in most cases, not the value in pixels.

Comment: Question says "I need the exact computed line-height in pixels, not values of the sort 1.2em, normal or heuristics like fontSize * 1.5."

Answer (score 3):

```
$("span").css( "line-height");
```

Retrieves the computed px value as a string "16px" for example. It uses IE's `currentStyle` or the standard `getComputedStyle` under the covers. Which is kind of surprising seeing as when it works as a setter it does `elem.style.something = value` which is a whole different thing.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, of course. Unfortunately on WebKit browsers it returns the string "normal" unless I have set the `line-height` manually in advance. I am using jQuery 1.6.1. Does it have different behavior in later versions?

Comment: @RadanGanchev you are correct, it returns normal for some elements. `[].forEach.call( document.getElementsByTagName("*"), function(v){
console.log ( getComputedStyle(v).lineHeight );
});` Running that returns px value on this page for most elements though.

Comment: @Esailija yes, if you inspect the elements on this page, you'll see that most of them have a set `line-height` in the CSS and a few have default `line-height`. For the ones with the default `line-height` still "normal" is displayed. I tested it on my site, too and it still doesn't do the job.

Comment: @RadanGanchev I ran it on `fontSize` and I got px value for all - maybe the font-size px value is used as a line-height when it's normal? http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height

Comment: @Esailija yes, `fontSize` is computed correctly. Unfortunately, the line height is almost never equal to the font size. I think it is browser dependent and in most browsers it's something like `lineHeight = fontSize * 1.5` (that is for `line-height: normal`).

Comment: @RadanGanchev ok I think then a different approach is needed to solve your problem.. I didn't really understand what you are trying to do in the first place I admit. Can you give an example in jsfiddle?

Comment: @Esailija [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sXjDs/4/) is an example. Using some specific custom fonts makes the problem much more obvious. In my case a 5-6 pixel gap appears between the separate lines of the highlight `span`. What I need to do is find the exact height of these lines to make the span (respectively its background) stretch to fill the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the span is contained in a div.

you could set the div to position:relative

and the span as a block that takes 100% height.

In this way you will stretch the span as you want.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a9k2t/)
(note: to see the effect, change the background colour of the span to transparent. You should be able to see the red div.)

Comment: I am using a `span`, because I need an inline element. My goal is to mark some text which may start in the middle of a line. `display: block` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your design allows for it, you can apply inline-block to the elements you are targeting and then use `outerHeight` ...

```
var inlineHeight = $('.inline-height').css("display", "inline-block").outerHeight(); 
//console.log('Inline Height:' + inlineHeight);
```